# how to treat a shape as a graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics2d, shapes

I am doing a java project and I have a collection of shapes, i need to give a different color to every shape. 
For example in the collection I have squares and rectangles, Then I need to draw the squares in red and the rectangles in blue. I am thinking to set a shape as a graphics2D but I can not.

Comment: Really we need a specific thing you've tried to do and had a problem with to supply helpful advise

Comment: If what you need is more general advise then search for a graphics tutorial. For example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/

Comment: As states in your previous question, wrap the Shape and color details in a proxy object, this allows you to carry the information that's required in a centralised object. Alternatively, you could use a HashMap keyed to the Shape which associates the color with it and look this information up when you paint.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of a shape and that of a Graphics2D are completely orthogonal -- you can't think of a Shape as a Graphics2D object it doesn't make any sense whatsoever as a shape is a collection of points and a Graphics2D object is like a brush that paints the points ... they just don't jibe. Also, a Shape is something that persists throughout the program while a Graphics object can be swapped at the whim of the JVM, and this is completely out of your control.

The solution: completely rethink what you're doing, but don't bark up this tree as it will only lead to misery. If you need more help, *as we've suggested before*, please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Also, if you want to connect a Shape with a color, then consider creating a wrapper class that holds your Shape object and your Color object together. Another option is to use a `Map<Shape, Color>`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to make an sscce, the most I can post is what I post before; I explain it by words but to make a compilable code is unreachable for me, but thanks for trying to help me

Comment: @vilal_ I've yet to see you even try to create the sscce. Why not try as you've nothing to lose. Until you do, I fear that you may continue to get answers that disappoint you, and questions that disappoint us.

Comment: I think thats the point, if you have no code to start with then what you want is a tutorial not stack overflow

Comment: I have code, but the problem is I am not able for the moment to maje an sscce so that is why this is not very easy, but thank you

Comment: Code that you have writen that *should* run counts as a SSCCE, the point is that you try something find a specific problem, ask about the specific question. Questions along the line of 'Teach me this entire technique' are not a good fit for stack overflow (but there are many good tutorials)

Comment: @RichardTingle indeed. Whenever trying to implement something new or challenging, you should test it in a small runnable program first before trying to add it to your larger program.

Comment: The OP did have a SSCCE but they deleted the post for some reason

Comment: @MadProgrammer  That is a habit of this person.  They have already been asked not to do that, but seem intent on ignoring that advice (as well as most other advice offered).

Comment: @AndrewThompson God forbid they finally abandon there current approach to actually resolve there question :P